# Creating a generic Checkbox_Click VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, spreadsheet

I am creating an excel file that is a checklist, currently i have 73 checkboxes in Column D, where in column E it will populate the name of the user based on the username in the options field.

Currently i Have code such as:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = 1 Then
   Range("E3").Value = Application.UserName
   Else: Range("E3").Value = ""
 End If
End Sub
Sub CheckBox2_Click() 
If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 2").Value = 1 Then
   Range("E4").Value = Application.UserName
   Else: Range("E4").Value = ""
 End If
End Sub
```

For each checkbox in column D. It does work but I need to now replicate Column D into Columns F,H,J,L for other days of the week and I am curious if there is a faster way to do this and a cleaner way to do this instead of having a long list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. You will have to format each checkbox and assign this macro to each of them, from the Format | Assign Macro option.

```
Sub Generic_ChkBox()
Dim cbName As String
Dim cbCell As Range
Dim printValue as String

cbName = Application.Caller

Set cbCell = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(cbName).TopLeftCell

Select Case cbCell.Column
    Case 4
        'prints the username in column E
        printValue = Application.UserName
    Case 6
        'prints "Something else" in column G
        printValue = "Something else"
    Case 8
        'prints "etc..." in column I, etc.
        printValue = "etc..."
    Case 10
        printValue = "etc..."
    Case 12
        printValue = "etc..."
End Select

If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(cbName).Value = 1 Then
    cbCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = printValue
Else
    cbCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just for clarity, you can select all the checkboxes and then assign the macro to all of them in one action.

Comment: `Application.Caller` really is useful for multiple repetitive actions. Has saved me a number of times.

Comment: @DavidZemens it wasn't a question, it was an observation.

Comment: My mistake -sorry I thought you were asking a follow-up.

Comment: This works, except it puts the name in E2 instead of E3.
I resolved this by changing the offset to (1,1) In case someone was curios

Comment: Could be due to the alignment of your checkboxes. I use the `.TopLeftCell` property, so if the checkbox is not aligned within D3, then it will not write to E3.  Cheers!

Comment: Ah that Makes sense, thanks for the help, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed your are going to assign the username value to next cell of CheckBox. 
For D4 is having checkbox then value will be E4.

```
Sub ProcessAllCheckBox()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape
 Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:Z").ClearContents
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
   If chk.Value = 1 Then
     Set s = ws.Shapes(chk.Caption)
     Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(s.TopLeftCell.Row, s.TopLeftCell.Column + 1),  Cells(s.TopLeftCell.Row, s.TopLeftCell.Column + 1)).Value = Application.UserName
  End If
 Next
```

End Sub

Please update the below code in WorkShee Active

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
  chk.OnAction = "ProcessAllCheckBox"
Next
ProcessAllCheckBox
End Sub
```

Comment: Correct, for D3, it will update E3 etc.
I am running this one but getting a 400 error 
THe only change i made was sheet1 to sheet5 in the respective places.